# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I want to call postgresql procedure using StoredProcedureQuery. I am getting error. I didn't understand what the problem was. How can i solve the problem.

`

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("call test.pn_testforjava");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.setParameter(1,className);
query.execute();
```

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 24
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.executeWithFlags(PgCallableStatement.java:84)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:177)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyCallableStatement.execute(NewProxyCallableStatement.java:3214)
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:56)
        ... 7 more
```

`

I want to call postgresql procedure using StoredProcedureQuery. I am getting error. I didn't understand what the problem was. How can i solve the problem.

Comment: Only pass the [procedure name as argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createStoredProcedureQuery-java.lang.String-) `entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("test.pn_testforjava")`. If that won't work, try setting it up outside of `test` schema (or use `test_` instead of `test.` if that was supposed to be only a name prefix) `entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("test_pn_testforjava")`